# Powershell System.IO.StreamReader Read method

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm trying to learn how to use streams in PowerShell. I've been able to understand all of the methods in StreamReader except the Read(char[], In32, In32).

I've only been able to get this method to work using

```
[char[]]$ca = 'a','b','c','d','e'    
$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($inputFile)
$reader.Read($ca,0,$ca.Length)     
$reader.Close()
```

My question is how can use the Read method without creating an array before hand?  Do I have to create and array of 1024 chars if That is the amount of data I want to read into the buffer?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. In the example, `$ca` _is_ your buffer, and yes, you will have to create it before you can store data in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create the buffer array beforehand, but you don't need to initialize it:

```
$ca = [char[]]::new(1024)
$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($inputFile)
$reader.Read($ca,0,$ca.Length)     
$reader.Close()
```